# Download/transfer files to aws windows server in jenkins job

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I would like to download files to Jenkins work space before running the job. 
I would like to download from local machine to Jenkins on Aws server and also from file share to jenkins on aws machine.
These are big data files. I heard I can create a batch file but not sure how?

Please advise.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you want to have two jobs:

1. A job that fetches some big files and places them in workspace.
2. A job that reads the files from the same workspace of the previous job.

The [shared workspace plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shared+workspace+plugin) might be fit for you.